# exporting a canvas graph based on the id

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

I have multiple canvas graphs on my page and each graph has the options of being exported. My current issue is that all my exports are exporting the same first canvas/graph and i realized that the issue is that it is looking for the `canvas` tag name and downloading but i would like to specify which canvas to download so i am able to download all graphs individually.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<canvas height="260" *ngIf="chartLoaded" baseChart [colors]="colorsOverride" [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType"
                    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>

<div class="panel-footer">
    <a href="#" (click)="exportGraph($event)">Export Graph</a>
</div>
```

**Component file:**

```
 exportGraph(event:any){
    var anchor = event.target;
    anchor.href = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL();
    anchor.download = "export.png";
  }
```

how can i specify the export graph so that it is downloading each appropriate canvas - like passing in canvas id maybe or the id of the div in which the canvas is within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add an id to each one of your canvases,

```
 exportGraph(event:any){
    var anchor = event.target;
    anchor.href = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.toDataURL();
    anchor.download = "export.png";
  }
```

Should work, it should download the canvas element that is DIRECTLY before div that is holding the anchor based off the sample code you provided.

I don't have an angular setup right now but I did get this working with:

```
<script>
function exportGraph(){
    var anchor = event.target;
    anchor.href = event.target.parentNode.previousElementSibling.toDataURL();
    anchor.download = "export.png";
  }
</script>
<canvas height="260">

</canvas>

<div class="panel-footer">
    <a href="#" onClick="exportGraph()">Export Graph</a>
</div>
```

Comment: so if  i have 6 canvas/graphs will i have to write this exportGraph function 6 times with the 6 different id's?

Comment: @bluePearl oops, sorry, I missed part of your sample code, check out my updated answer. This should work for all your graphs if they're in the same format as the hmtl you provided.

Comment: when i tried this - everytime i click the export link the page reloads but nothing is downloaded.

Comment: @bluePearl There was a typo with the word "Previous". I edited my answer. I hope this works for you. I don't have angular setup here, but was able to get it with vanilla js.

Comment: HAH! Good catch - Thanks working as expected now. But do you think in general that this practice or method of going about this is appropriate?